# Android library multiple modules

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-productflavors

I am building a library on android, which is composed of a big core and several modules (let's name them A, B, C, D and E)
Those modules sometimes require another library and sometimes have things to add in the resulting manifest.

I would like to be able to build my core with any number of modules.
I started by creating flavors which are really useful but are a bit limited in my case. If I wanted to create a flavor for each cases it would mean creating A LOT of them!

edit: A gradle file to explain what I would like to do.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    flavorDimensions "libA", "libB", "libC", "libD", "libF"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 11
        versionName "3.1.0"
    }

    productFlavors {
        A {
          flavorDimension "libA"
        }

        B {
          flavorDimension "libB"
        }

        C {
          flavorDimension "libC"
        }

        D {
          flavorDimension "libD"
        }

        E {
          flavorDimension "libB"
        }

        F {
          flavorDimension "libF"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        A {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/A']
            }
        }

        B {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/B']
            }
        }

        C {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/C']
            }
        }

        D {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/D']
            }
        }

        E {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/E']
            }
        }

        F {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/F']
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'

    ACompile files('libs/A-2.1.0.jar')

    BCompile files('libs/B-4.1.0.jar')

    CCompile files('libs/C-5.1.0.jar')

    DCompile files('libs/D-1.01.jar')

    // same library as B, but different version
    ECompile files('libs/B-5.2.2.jar')

    // F nothing
}
```

What I would like to be able to produce is:

> A.aar
>  B.aar
>  C.aar
>  D.aar
>  E.aar
>  F.aar
>   A+B.aar
>  A+C.aar
>  A+D.aar
>  A+E.aar
>  A+F.aar
>   A+B+C.aar
>  A+B+D.aar
>  A+B+F.aar (since B and E are not
>   compatible)
>  A+C+D.aar
>  A+C+E.aar

etc. etc. etc...

When I try with this gradle file, and launch "gradlew assembleRelease" I only obtain:
A+B+C+D+F.aar and A+C+D+E+F.aar

What would be modified to obtain the result I'm looking for?

Is there a simpler way to do such a build?

Comment: no views and no answers :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create multiple standalone android library modules and use custom gradle scripts to pull and use the necessary modules

Comment: that would mean merging manifests and jars myself (and re-do the .aar if I want to push on maven repo)

Comment: Anything bad about doing that? Gradle makes doing those things dead easy compared to ant/maven

Comment: I edited the main post ;) I can use gradle script to merge manifest like merge(manifestA, manifestB) ?